# Computing a finite sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove the following: given the sequence $$a_m = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $m = 0, 1$} \\\frac{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+4)\cdots(\alpha+2(m-1))}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)\cdots(\alpha+m-1)} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ then, $$\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^m\binom{n}{m}a_m = \begin{cases}\frac{(n-1)!!}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+3)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)}& \text{if $n$ is even and $\ge 2$} \\0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$$

I understand that the left hand side in the last equation is the $n$-th difference $\Delta^na_0$, so basically I tried to compute each difference but it seems that a general formula is hard to find for $\Delta^na_k$. Can you help me? I have seen often that such problems can be attacked with special functions but unfortunately I don't have any experience :(. What do you suggest? Any hint would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: So here is the original problem: show that $$e^{-x}\left[1+x+\frac{\alpha+2}{\alpha+1}\cdot\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+4)}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}\cdot\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots\right]=$$$$1+\frac1{\alpha+1}\frac{x^2}{2^1\cdot1!}+\frac1{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+3)}\frac{x^4}{2^2\cdot2!}+\ldots$$. Doing the product one just compares the two series and obtains my equation above (if I interpreted correctly the pattern of the two series).

Comment: Maybe some [identities involving binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients) can be useful?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you do not need to precise $a_0=a_1=0$ since they are explicit from the formula which gives $a_m$.

Next, the $a_m$ simplify a lot when $m$ is even. For exemple
$$a_7=\frac{(\alpha +8) (\alpha +10) (\alpha +12)}{(\alpha +1) (\alpha +3) (\alpha +5)}\qquad a_8=\frac{(\alpha +8) (\alpha +10) (\alpha +12) (\alpha +14)}{(\alpha +1) (\alpha +3)
   (\alpha +5) (\alpha +7)}$$

Using Pochhammer symbols
$$a_m=2^{m-1}\frac{ \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}+1\right)_{m-1}}{(\alpha +1)_{m-1}}$$
$$S_n=\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^m\binom{n}{m}\,a_m =\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2 \sqrt{\pi } }\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha +1}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+\alpha
   +1)\right)}$$ If I am not mistaken, we do not obtain the same formula for $S_n$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that in the case $m=0, 1$ then $1$ is explicit. Anyway I don't understand the last equation (clearly because I have no background in special functions). I will review my calculations, and edit the question if I find a mistake. Anyway I'll also edit it to include the original problem from which I derived my equation. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Peanut. Give me one $\alpha$ and one $n$ of your choice and we shall compare. Just kidding, I hope that your last name is not *Butter* ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I edited my question. I revised my calculations and I think they are fine. Let me know what you think about the problem statement :)

Comment: @Peanut. Thanks for editing. The problem is correct. But why the $(-1)^m$ ?

Comment: It results from the first multiplication, since $e^{-x}$ has alternating signs. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Peanut. Why don't you multiply each side by $e^x$ ?

Comment: That actually could simplify the calculations! Let me try...It's kind of a reverse equation...

Comment: I'm not sure the calculations are simpler :(

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to prove the original problem? (since you know it is correct I guess so), or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @Peanut. Being tricky, I made a series expansion of the lhs around $x=0$ and "observed" the result (which is the rhs).

Comment: AHHHH this one is tough!!! If you are willing to think about it and edit your answer, I will upvote and accept it :)

Comment: @Peanut. This would not be a proof. By the way, this look to be balckmail ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Claude I'm sorry to bother you again. How did you obtain the last expression for $S_n$?

Answer (score 2):

From the definition, of the [Pochhammer symbol](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/02/), $$(a)_n=\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)}$$we can express
\begin{equation}
  a_m=2^m\frac{ \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)_{m}}{(\alpha )_{m}}
 \end{equation}
with $a_0=a_1=1$. (The expression given by @ClaudeLeibovici can be retrieved by remarking that
\begin{equation}
  (s+1)_{m-1}=\frac{\Gamma(s+m)}{\Gamma(s+1)}=\frac{1}{s}\frac{\Gamma(s+m)}{\Gamma(s)}=\frac{1}{s}(s)_m
 \end{equation}
The  series proposed in the edit can be expressed as a [confluent hypergeometric function](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.20.02.0001.01)
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}&= 1+x+\frac{\alpha+2}{\alpha+1}\cdot\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+4)}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}\cdot\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots\\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{ \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)_{k}}{(\alpha )_{k}}\frac{(2x)^k}{k!}\\
 &=\,_1F_1\left(  \frac{\alpha}{2},\alpha;2x \right)
 \end{align}
It can be recognized as related to a [modified Bessel function](http://functions.wolfram.com/03.02.26.0003.01)
\begin{equation}
  I_\nu(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}z^\nu e^{-z}}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\,_1F_1\left(  \nu+\frac{1}{2},2\nu+1;2z \right)
 \end{equation}
Here, taking $\nu=(\alpha-1)/2$, we find
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}=2^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{\alpha+1}{2} \right)x^{\frac{1-\alpha}{2}}e^{x}I_{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}(x)
 \end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
  e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}=\Gamma\left( \frac{\alpha+1}{2} \right)\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{\frac{1-\alpha}{2}}e^{x}I_{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}(x)
 \end{equation}
From the [series expansion](http://functions.wolfram.com/03.02.06.0002.01)
\begin{align}
  I_\nu(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+\nu+1)k!}\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{2k+\nu}\\
  &=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^\nu\left( 1+\frac{z^2}{4(\nu+1)}+\frac{z^4}{32(\nu+1)(\nu+2)}+\ldots \right)
 \end{align}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
   e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}=1+\frac1{\alpha+1}\frac{x^2}{2^1\cdot1!}+\frac1{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+3)}\frac{x^4}{2^2\cdot2!}+\ldots
 \end{equation}
as expected

Comment: I think I would appreciate this if I knew a little bit more about special functions. Where do I find a (easy) proof of the last equality for $I_v$?

Comment: The series expansion around $z=0$ of the modified Bessel function $I_\nu(z)$ can be found by applying the Frobenius method to the modified Bessel's equation. Alternatively, it can be deduced from that of $J_\nu(z)$ by the expression $I_\nu(x)=i^{-\nu}J_\nu(ix)$.

Comment: I have no idea what $J$ is, but thanks for your answer. Still I'm looking for a more elementary approach.